# git merge is changing files against the merge strategy

Tags: git, merge, django-migrations

I have a django project.  I recently worked out that I want all the branches to apply a merge strategy of always choosing the current content of the migrations/ folders and the development database, so that the development in each branch is coherent.  I followed this advice: [Medium: merge.ours.driver true](https://medium.com/@porteneuve/how-to-make-git-preserve-specific-files-while-merging-18c92343826b)

(Migrations are mostly auto-generated Python scripts that manage changes to the database schema to keep the database in step with the Python classes that describe the models. The dev database is sqlite3. I want to be able to switch to any branch of any other devs and immediately start running their setup with their dev data, so I want the migrations and database committed. Merging can only be done at the level of the python classes (models.Model) - multiple, incoherent migrations files just don't work.)

But today I was trying to merge changes from a branch into my current branch and two migrations files were being overwritten, or possibly two local files were being deleted and replaced with two alternatives.

This is what I think happened -

1. In early November, before we adopted the merge=ours driver, I deleted the two migrations and replaced them with different migrations and then committed them, pleased I had resolved the error though it cost me my database.
2. My colleague, whose branch I'm trying to merge has progressed on from there, while
   2a or 1b.  I progressed from an earlier node for some ... reason.
3. Today, git sees that last time those files were there, I chose to delete them and put new ones in their place, and repeats that confidently. But its not what I want. To make those files usable, I'd need the database and the entire contents (pretty much) of every migrations folder to be back at that early November state. Still, since I specified everything in migrations/ was now to use a "merge ours" driver, I'm not sure why git wouldn't treat that as a superseding rule.

Do I need to investigate more, or is there some kind of option (--no-ff?) that will make this merge an explicit conflict to be resolved, or do I just need to hide copies those files in a safe place and then replace them after the merge, thus teaching git a lesson about which files I prefer>

```
* 169b996 (HEAD -> MyBranch) updated main merged to MyBranch, migrations reconciled and applied.
*   256efd5 Merge branch 'main' into MyBranch
|\
| *   246de6b (origin/main, main) local main merged to origin/main. migrate and add db.sqlite3 to branch record.
| |\
| | * 4ab0a0a (origin/feature/Coworker2_working) app: Added roleset to models so that 
| | * d03637e Updated Coworker2 apps to reflect addition of 
* | | ca27cbd (origin/MyBranch) remove workteams; set up email for password update; improve admin of contenttrace
* | | 48568f7 fix gitattributes again
* | | 420504c alternative 'target_groups' code and models introduced (workteam)
* | | 952ca6c Add models for Locale, LocLine, Area, Point.  Delete response JE fields etc
* | | 08fb23c change redacted 
* | | a49a7ec Revisions to app1 and app2
* | | 15be6ac add Copy/Move action to ModelAdmin.
* | | 9780767  organisation and extension; show-hide sources etc.
|/ /
* | 113bad1 Serve documents to SourceAdmin
* | 63a09fb Serve documents to SourceAdmin
|/
* e6c8870 handle change from task to tasks in models.
* 1d74478 Fix confused migrations folders in branch.  Add protec_db and migrate dev database to latest models.
* 5bd0eff Fix confused migrations folders in branch.  Add protec_db and migrate dev database to latest models.
* c61d58c bugfix/dp step changed to task
* 0f2c30a bugfix\dp models removing step in favour of task
* 698d2b4 git merge strategy=ours for migrations & db.sqlite3
*   f1e442d Merge pull request #29 in ~ME/origin from Coworker 1 to main
|\
| | * 3846405 (origin/Coworker1) Added a startup app that users can clone to start a new app
| | * 719b4bd Fixed the tree question list, it displays only the questioned assigned to the task now, ratings importance fixed as well
| | * 67c040d Added an edit icon in the projects page that directs the user to the admin page of the project
| | * 3fd8b1a Added reason icon and improved results page for the intuitive app
| | * f0de7fe Fixed merge, move, and delete issues in the tree question app
| | * 75a6d45 Updated the projects app middleware to detect PATCH & DELETE requests
| | * b852a24 New migrations
| | * 691b691 Removed redundant app links in the sidebar
| | * bc09ca5 cpt, intuitive, stitching, and mst works with the projects app
| | * ca180ed Refactored theme templates, updated the polls, tree question, and history tracker to use my base template, improved the design of the projects app
```

This is just after I merged the Coworker1 branch:

```
*   9cb8c17 (HEAD -> MyBranch) Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/Coworker1' into MyBranch
|\
| * 3846405 (origin/Coworker1) Added a startup app that users can clone to start a new app
| * 719b4bd Fixed the tree question list, it displays only the questioned assigned to the task now, ratings importance fixed as well
| * 67c040d Added an edit icon in the projects page that directs the user to the admin page of the project
| * 3fd8b1a Added reason icon and improved results page for the intuitive app
| * f0de7fe Fixed merge, move, and delete issues in the tree question app
| * 75a6d45 Updated the projects app middleware to detect PATCH & DELETE requests
| * b852a24 New migrations
| * 691b691 Removed redundant app links in the sidebar
| * bc09ca5 cpt, intuitive, stitching, and mst works with the projects app
| * ca180ed Refactored theme templates, updated the polls, tree question, and history tracker to use my base template, improved the design of the projects app
* | 83320e5 update dev db
* | 169b996 updated main merged to MyBranch_data, migrations reconciled and applied.
```

TBH, I'm not seeing much evidence that my merge strategy is actually being applied to the folders.
but:

```
=>git config --global --list
merge.ours.driver=true

# .gitattributes
migrations/ merge=ours
db.sqlite3 binary
db.sqlite3 merge=ours
```

Many thanks for your advice:

Comment: Does your question boils down to : "Why, with `merge=ours` driver, when I merge my changes into `master`, does `git` keep the version in `master` instead of my version ?"

Comment: No I don't think so. I am pulling changes from a colleagues branch into my branch, to resolve conflicts before merging all to our 'main.'  Committed file changes in his branch are superseding 'preserved' files from my branch.  These changes would have happened before the "merge=ours driver."  (I am not sure what to do to get a precise diagnosis.)

Comment: Ok. Can you add to your question a view of your repo before the merge ? For example : copy paste the output of `git log --oneline --graph your/branch your/colleagues/branch`